# How to send result of "requests.get" to another socket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I`m trying to make some kind of specialized proxy server for my needs. 
Application listen to some port and when I connect there using (for example) cURL it opens a socket (lets call it *"my_socket"* ). I get some data from there, modify it according to my needs and make a request to another server using HTTPS:

```
my_request = "https://whatever.com/params"
my_response = requests.get(my_request)
```

Now I want to send my_response with all headers and payload to the open socket. Some kind of

```
my_socket.send(my_response)
```

but socket accepts **byte-like** objects and *my_response* is **HTTPResponse**. This cause error. 
Could anybody advise me how to convert **HTTPResponce** to bytes or may be I can use any other approach to transfer my data? I think I can manually extract all the data from *my_response* and manually assemble the response, but maybe there is any easier way?
Thanks.

**Update**
I tried

```
my_socket.send(my_response.content)
```

but other side can not decode it to any text. It looks like this:

```
curl -o /dev/null -v -s -k "http://127.0.0.1:8080/my_cool_request"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /my_cool_request HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
{ [16380 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

**Update2**. 
I send headers from *my_response.headers*.

```
    my_lenth=len(my_response.content)
    my_header="HTTP/1.1 " + str(my_response.status_code)+" " + my_response.reason
    for key in my_response.headers:
        my_header+=key+": "+r.headers[key]+"\n"
    my_header+="Content-Length: "+str(my_lenth)+"\n"
    header_encoded=my_header.encode()
    my_socket.send (header_encoded)
    my_socket.send(r.content)
```

This is not the final version, because I still get an error from my cURL:

```
* Illegal or missing hexadecimal sequence in chunked-encoding
```

[There is an explanation why it is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593230/http-illegal-chunked-encoding)

Comment: This might be helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233340/sending-string-via-socket-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233340/sending-string-via-socket-python)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sofian said, you can use **response.content.**
But in general, you should know that if you have a string object, you can do
**str.encode()** to make it a byte-like object;

```
x = "hello, world!"
x.encode()
```

Then to get it back to a string, use **str.decode()**

```
x = b"hello, world!"
print(x.decode())
```

Comment: Thanks for update. Correct me if I`m wrong, but response.content is already bytes and no need to decode them.

Comment: @ZeleniyZmey yes, it is bytes and you don't need to encode them to byte string.

Answer (score 0):

the **content** variable of the Response-Class is a byte-like object:

```
response = requests.get("https://google.com")
mySocket.send(response.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried response.content, but it seems .content contains just a payload without headers. Therefore when I use this construction I do not get response code and other information. Just a payload.